# search in multidimensional array and assign to other select elements in php

Tags: php

I have a multidimensional array listed bellow

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [order_number] => R5/20   
            [production_codes] => Array
                (
                    [0] =>  R5 0069
                    [1] => R5 0068
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [order_number] => R3/20   
            [production_codes] => Array
                (
                    [0] =>  R3 0055
                    [1] => R3 0054
                    [2] => R3 0053
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [order_number] => R6/19 
            [production_codes] => Array
                (
                    [0] =>  R6 0002
                )

        )

)
```

what I need is when someone select a specific order number form dropdown, only production codes relevant to that selected order number shows in next dropdown. My html code is

```
<div class="row marker_size_row_class" id="markerSizeRow_1">
                          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                            <label>Select Order Number <i class="zmdi required-staric">*</i></label>
                            <div class="input-group masked-input mb-3">
                              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="zmdi zmdi-dot-circle-alt"></i></span>
                              </div>
                              <select class="form-control show-tick ms select2" id="markerSize_1" name="variable[1][order_numbers]" data-placeholder="Select Marker Size" required>
                                <?php foreach ($order_production_codes as $key => $order_number) {?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $order_number['order_number']; ?>"><?php echo $order_number['order_number']; ?></option>
                                <?php } ?>
                              </select>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                            <label>Select Production Code <i class="zmdi required-staric">*</i></label>
                            <div class="input-group masked-input mb-3">
                              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="zmdi zmdi-dot-circle-alt"></i></span>
                              </div>
                              <select class="form-control show-tick ms select2" id="markerSize_1" name="variable[1][production_code]" data-placeholder="Select Marker Size" required>
                                
                              </select>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          
                        </div>
```

View of my html is also attached in screen short
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1C0yr.png)

Comment: You could filter out what you need using [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and then fetch `$result[0]['production_codes']` (your order should be the only element after filtering if there are no duplicates).

Comment: well I would use frontend to manage it. Check what are linked selects : http://www.infimum.dk/HTML/multiselect.html

Answer (score 0):

you need to make an ajax call while selecting the **order number** and then for adding product code in the particular input box you need to run the for each loop on the ajax response using jquery or javascript